# Moving a Point Along a Line in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, 2d, line

Let's say that I have the coordinates of a line (25,35 45,65, 30,85 - It would be a two part line). I need to move a point (car) along that line at a constant distance every frame. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to move it along a *single* line segment at constant speed?

Comment: No, but as soon as I can move along single line segments it should be easy to just repeat the process from the end of the previous line

Comment: How do you you do it with just a single line then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the line (25,35 45,65). The vector from the beginning to the end is (20, 30). To move a point (x,y) in that direction, we could just add that vector:

V = (20, 30)
(x,y) => (x+20, y+30).

If we start at the beginning of the line, we'll arrive at the end.
But that's too big a step. We want something smaller but in the same direction, so we multiply the vector by, say, 0.1:

V = (2, 3)
(x,y) => (x+2, y+3) => (x+4, y+6) => ...

It's convenient to **normalize**, that is to make its length 1, which we do by dividing by its length:

V => V/|V| = (2,3)/sqrt(2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup>) = (7.21, 10.82)

Then you can just multiply that by whatever step size you want.

Comment: Aww, I knew there should be an easier way!

Comment: Very cool! I thought it was possible using vectors, but O could not figure it out.

Comment: I know your method works, but I am having a tough time understanding your notation. Could you please just rewrite those three lines in pseudo-JavaScript? I am only in ninth grade and your math is above my level :) Thanks!

Comment: To normalize a given vector (X, Y), in this case (20, 30), you first get the length (or magnitude) of that vector and then divide the components by this length. The length is `Math.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)`. So (20, 30) length is `Math.sqrt(20*20 + 30*30)` and (20, 30) normalized would be `(20 / length, 30 / length)`

Comment: O.K., got it! That completely answers my question!

Answer (score 24):

Hey, so you have the coordinates (25,35) (45,65) (30,85) for your 2 lines, The point you want to move is going to be placed at the first of these coordinates (25,35) and you want it to move towards the second coordinate (45,65) (the end of the first line segment).

The first step is to get the orientation in which the point is going to move, the orientation is the angle between the point position and the target position. To find this angle you can use the `Math.atan2()`, passing in as the first argument the `target position Y - the point position Y`, and as the second argument the `target position X - the point position X`.

```
var Point = {X: 25, Y: 35};
var Target = {X:45, Y:65};

var Angle = Math.atan2(Target.Y - Point.Y, Target.X - Point.X);
```

Now get the Sine and Cosine of that angle, the Sine is the value to move along the Y axis, and the Cosine is how much to move on the X axis. Multiply the sine and cosine by the distance you want to move each frame.

```
var Per_Frame_Distance = 2;
var Sin = Math.sin(Angle) * Per_Frame_Distance;
var Cos = Math.cos(Angle) * Per_Frame_Distance;
```

Ok, what is left do to now is just setup the redraw method where you add the sine to the point's Y position and the cosine to the point's X position at each call. Check if the point has arrived to it's destination then do the same process to move towards the end of the second line segment.

Comment: Thank you all for the excellent answers! This is my first stack overflow question and I am glad to see that such a great resource is available to programmers! Thanks again, C.Ruhl

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 16):

8 years too late but someone may find this useful. This method is far faster given it doesn't uses stuff like atan, cos, sin and square root of which all are slow.

```
function getPositionAlongTheLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, percentage) {
    return {x : x1 * (1.0 - percentage) + x2 * percentage, y : y1 * (1.0 - percentage) + y2 * percentage};
}
```

Pass percentage as value between 0 and 1 where 0 is start of the line and 1 being the end.

```
var xy = getPositionAlongTheLine(100, 200, 500, 666, 0.5);
console.log(xy.x, xy.y);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Excellent! This is very useful. I will use this for a visualizer I am working on :) Thank you.

Comment: Simple and effective, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's not so obvious how to translate a mathematical formula into a code. The following is an implementation of a function which moves a point specified distance along a line. It uses vector notation:

```
function travel(x, y, dx, x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    var point = new Vector(x, y),
        begin = new Vector(x1, y1),
        end = new Vector(x2, y2);
    return end.sub(begin).norm().mul(dx).add(point);
}

class Vector
{
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    clone() {
        return new this.constructor(this.x, this.y);
    }

    add(v) {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
        return this;
    }

    sub(v) {
        this.x = this.x - v.x;
        this.y = this.y - v.y;
        return this;
    }

    mul(x) {
        this.x *= x;
        this.y *= x;
        return this;
    }

    div(x) {
        this.x /= x;
        this.y /= x;
        return this;
    }

    get mag() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    }

    norm() {
        var mag = this.mag;
        if (mag > 0) {
            this.div(mag);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

And a version without `Vector` class:

```
function travel(x, y, dx, x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    var a = {x: x2 - x1, y: y2 - y1},
        mag = Math.sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y);
    if (mag == 0) {
        a.x = a.y = 0;
    }
    else {
        a.x = a.x/mag*dx;
        a.y = a.y/mag*dx;
    }
    return {x: x + a.x, y: y + a.y};
}
```