# HTML Canvas moving an object in a direction at a constant speed?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm building pong to learn some of the basics of the drawing API for canvas. However, I'm struggling with one of the more basic elements of getting the ball moving. Right now, I'm randomly generating a set of co-ordinates for it to move towards, but I have no idea how to get it to actually move there at a constant speed of my choosing.

The ball starts at a base speed and gets faster over time.

So how does something like this work? How do I calculate how far to move the ball on the X and Y axis?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985072/moving-a-point-along-a-line-in-javascript-canvas/5995931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a version of pong using canvas a little while back [view it here](http://www.stevekane.com.au/test/canvas/pong.html) where you can view the source.

To do the ball animation I've just used a variable for the `x` and `y` velocities, some for the ball's `x` and `y` coordinates and an animation function that loops through using `setInterval()`

Here's a small sample of it (minus all the drawing code of course)

```
velX = 5;
velY = 2;
ballPosX = 100;
ballPosY = 50;
radius = 10;

// loop through 20fps
setInterval(animate,50);

function animate() {
    // draw ball at ballPosX, ballPosY coordinates
    ctx.arc(ballPosX,ballPosY, radius,0,Math.PI * 180, false)
    // fill in colours etc

    // move ball
    ballPosX += velX;
    ballPosY += velY;

    // do boundary detection for bounce
    if (ballPosX + radius > ctx.width || ballPosX - radius < 0) {
        // change velX to negative to bounce the ball the oposite X direction
        velX *= -1;
    }
    // do the same for velY
}
```

That should give you an idea of how it all works. Obviously I can't type the entire code in here. But if you head to that link you can see the source. It's mostly commented :)

Steve

Comment: I know that this is an older post, but I was looking through your code and I noticed a redundancy in the source code on your website.  When you declare your variables, you have an empty `ctx`, yet in each function where `ctx` is used (`play()` and `start()`) you define `ctx` as the same value.  You did the same with `canvas`.  Why not just set the values at the beginning?

Comment: Hi Michael, yep you're right. I didn't realise I had set it in the onload function (start()). That's what happens when you code things late at night :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have somewhere to store its velocity, and increment it until some other force acted on it to change its velocity/direction (easy way of making the ball bounce is just to negate the directions the ball is travelling in).

To move an element towards something, calculate the distance between the element and its target as an `x` and `y` delta. To move it, decrease these values at whatever rate you choose.

You should be using a separate `setTimeout()` that draws all these elements.

Comment: I got the redrawing functionality down already, I'm only having problems with moving the ball in the right direction at the right speed. I'll see if I can figure out how to implement it based on the x y delta idea.