# UIPanGestureRecognizer - drag UIView only within a line path connecting 2 points

Tags: ios, swift, math, formula, uigesturerecognizer

I have a line (`CAShapeLayer`) which is connecting two points. Those two points can be anywhere on the screen and their coordinates are known. The point in the middle also has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but I want it to be draggable only within the line (so it can't leave the line - the line must go directly through the center of the middle dot at any time).

I know that I can calculate the draggable position of the point with

```
let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
```

and limit it by X or Y axis but what kind of calculation is needed here to drag it only within the line?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the two end points to compute the slope-intercept form if the line between them (y= mx + b).  Then plug the x-coordinate from the translation point into the line equation to calculate y.  Finally, position the draggable point at (x, y).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers! I managed to find the most suitable solution. I use the formula from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383437/1088286

```
function getPositionAlongTheLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, percentage) {
    return {x : x1 * (1.0 - percentage) + x2 * percentage, y : y1 * (1.0 - percentage) + y2 * percentage};
}
```

And that is the code I use in `didMove:` `UIPanGestureRecogniser` method:

```
            touchPoint.center = getPositionAlongTheLine(firstPoint: mainPoint1,
                                                        secondPoint: mainPoint2,
                                                        percentage: percentage)
```

Where mainPoint1 and mainPoint2 are the side buttons. Works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the "draggable circle" on the line by using a function to calculate the "closest point":

```
// get closest point on a line from a third point
private func closestPoint(_ pt1: CGPoint, pt2: CGPoint, pt3: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let vx = pt2.x - pt1.x
    let vy = pt2.y - pt1.y
    let ax = pt3.x - pt1.x
    let ay = pt3.y - pt1.y
    let u = (ax * vx + ay * vy) / (vx * vx + vy * vy)
    return CGPoint(x: pt1.x + vx * u, y: pt1.y + vy * u)
}
```

Here's a demo implementation, using a `CAShapeLayer` for the line, another `CAShapeLayer` for the "draggable circle" and tracking the movement using `touchesBegan` / `touchesMoved`. If you want to use a view and pan gestures for the "draggable circle" the idea will be the same (and should be easy to convert):

`UIView` subclass:

```
class StayOnLineView: UIView {

    public var lineEnds: [CGPoint] = [.zero, .zero] {
        didSet {
            guard lineEnds.count == 2 else {
                fatalError("lineEnds must be 2 points!")
            }
            linePT1 = lineEnds[0]
            linePT2 = lineEnds[1]
            minX = min(linePT1.x, linePT2.x)
            maxX = max(linePT1.x, linePT2.x)
            minY = min(linePT1.y, linePT2.y)
            maxY = max(linePT1.y, linePT2.y)
            currentDragPoint = centerPointOnLine(linePT1, pt2: linePT2)
        }
    }

    private var minX: CGFloat = 0
    private var minY: CGFloat = 0
    private var maxX: CGFloat = 0
    private var maxY: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var linePT1: CGPoint = .zero
    private var linePT2: CGPoint = .zero
    
    private var currentDragPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    private var isDragging: Bool = false
    
    private let lineLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let dragCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let dragCircleDiameter: CGFloat = 24

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
        lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 4
        
        layer.addSublayer(dragCircleLayer)
        dragCircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        dragCircleLayer.lineWidth = 2
        dragCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
    }
    
    func centerPointOnLine(_ pt1: CGPoint, pt2: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: pt1.x + ((pt2.x - pt1.x) * 0.5), y: pt1.y + ((pt2.y - pt1.y) * 0.5))
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: self)

            let dragRect = CGRect(x: currentDragPoint.x - dragCircleDiameter * 0.5, y: currentDragPoint.y - dragCircleDiameter * 0.5, width: dragCircleDiameter, height: dragCircleDiameter)
            let dragPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: dragRect)

            // only start dragging if touch is inside draggableCircle
            isDragging = dragPath.contains(position)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isDragging {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let position = touch.location(in: self)

                // get closest point on the line from the touch
                let p = closestPoint(linePT1, pt2: linePT2, pt3: position)

                // keep point from going past the ends of the line
                let x = min(max(p.x, minX), maxX)
                let y = min(max(p.y, minY), maxY)

                // update current drag point
                currentDragPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

                setNeedsLayout()
                layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isDragging = false
    }

    // get closest point on a line from a third point
    private func closestPoint(_ pt1: CGPoint, pt2: CGPoint, pt3: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let vx = pt2.x - pt1.x
        let vy = pt2.y - pt1.y
        let ax = pt3.x - pt1.x
        let ay = pt3.y - pt1.y
        let u = (ax * vx + ay * vy) / (vx * vx + vy * vy)
        return CGPoint(x: pt1.x + vx * u, y: pt1.y + vy * u)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: linePT1)
        linePath.addLine(to: linePT2)
        lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
        
        let dragCircleRect = CGRect(x: currentDragPoint.x - dragCircleDiameter * 0.5, y: currentDragPoint.y - dragCircleDiameter * 0.5, width: dragCircleDiameter, height: dragCircleDiameter)
        let dragCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: dragCircleRect)
        dragCircleLayer.path = dragCirclePath.cgPath
        
    }
    
}
```

Example View Controller:

```
class DragOnLineViewController: UIViewController {

    let testView = StayOnLineView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        testView.lineEnds = [
            CGPoint(x: 80.0, y: 80.0),
            CGPoint(x: testView.frame.width - 80.0, y: testView.frame.height - 80.0)
        ]

    }
}
```

---

**Edit** - simple example dragging a `UIView` with a pan gesture instead of dragging a `CAShapeLayer` using touches...

Simple `UIView` subclass - draws a line between two points:

```
class LineView: UIView {
    
    public var lineEnds: [CGPoint] = [.zero, .zero] {
        didSet {
            guard lineEnds.count == 2 else {
                fatalError("lineEnds must be 2 points!")
            }
        }
    }

    private let lineLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
        lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 4
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard lineEnds.count == 2 else {
            return
        }
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: lineEnds[0])
        linePath.addLine(to: lineEnds[1])
        lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

Basic "draggable" view, using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but limiting movement to a line between two points:

```
class DraggableCircleView: UIView {

    public var lineEnds: [CGPoint] = [.zero, .zero] {
        didSet {
            guard lineEnds.count == 2 else {
                fatalError("lineEnds must be 2 points!")
            }
            linePT1 = lineEnds[0]
            linePT2 = lineEnds[1]
            minX = min(linePT1.x, linePT2.x)
            maxX = max(linePT1.x, linePT2.x)
            minY = min(linePT1.y, linePT2.y)
            maxY = max(linePT1.y, linePT2.y)
            center = centerPointOnLine(linePT1, pt2: linePT2)
        }
    }
    
    private var minX: CGFloat = 0
    private var minY: CGFloat = 0
    private var maxX: CGFloat = 0
    private var maxY: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var linePT1: CGPoint = .zero
    private var linePT2: CGPoint = .zero

    private var startPoint: CGPoint = .zero

    private let dragCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        layer.addSublayer(dragCircleLayer)
        dragCircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        dragCircleLayer.lineWidth = 2
        dragCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panHandler(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(p)
    }
    
    @objc func panHandler(_ g: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        let t = g.translation(in: self)
        switch g.state {
        case .began:
            startPoint = center

        case .changed:
            let newPoint = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + t.x, y: startPoint.y + t.y)
            
            // get closest point on the line from the touch
            let p = closestPoint(linePT1, pt2: linePT2, pt3: newPoint)
            
            // keep point from going past the ends of the line
            let x = min(max(p.x, minX), maxX)
            let y = min(max(p.y, minY), maxY)
            
            // update current center point
            center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let dragCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)
        dragCircleLayer.path = dragCirclePath.cgPath
    }
    
    func centerPointOnLine(_ pt1: CGPoint, pt2: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: pt1.x + ((pt2.x - pt1.x) * 0.5), y: pt1.y + ((pt2.y - pt1.y) * 0.5))
    }

    // get closest point on a line from a third point
    private func closestPoint(_ pt1: CGPoint, pt2: CGPoint, pt3: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let vx = pt2.x - pt1.x
        let vy = pt2.y - pt1.y
        let ax = pt3.x - pt1.x
        let ay = pt3.y - pt1.y
        let u = (ax * vx + ay * vy) / (vx * vx + vy * vy)
        return CGPoint(x: pt1.x + vx * u, y: pt1.y + vy * u)
    }
    
}
```

Simple view controller example with `LineView` and `DraggableCircleView`:

```
class DragViewOnLineViewController: UIViewController {

    let dragCircleView = DraggableCircleView()
    
    let lineView = LineView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(lineView)
        lineView.backgroundColor = .green
        
        lineView.addSubview(dragCircleView)
        dragCircleView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            lineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            lineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            lineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        lineView.lineEnds = [
            CGPoint(x: 80.0, y: 80.0),
            CGPoint(x: lineView.frame.width - 80.0, y: lineView.frame.height - 80.0)
        ]
        
        dragCircleView.lineEnds = lineView.lineEnds
        
    }
}
```